# Calculate rotation angle with PanGestureRecognizer for analog clock hand

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gesture

I am trying to rotate the clock hands using PanGestureRecognizer for BoxView.

Currently I can correctly rotate the hand, but only on one side of the clock, on the other side the hand does not move correctly. Also, the coordinates for some reason depend on how many times you rotate the arrow.

My OnPanUpdated function

```
switch (e.StatusType)
{
    case GestureStatus.Running:
        Point UpdatedPan = new Point(e.TotalX, e.TotalY);
        UpdateHandRotation(hourHand, UpdatedPan);
        break;
}
```

And the main function

```
private void UpdateHandRotation(BoxView hand, Point UpdatedPan)
{
    // Get current hand rotation in radians
    double r = hand.Rotation * Math.PI / 180;
    Point center = new Point(absoluteLayout.Width / 2, absoluteLayout.Height / 2);
    double radius = 0.45 * Math.Min(absoluteLayout.Width, absoluteLayout.Height);

    double handEndX = Math.Cos(r) * radius + center.X;
    double handEndY = Math.Sin(r) * radius + center.Y;

    double movedEndX = handEndX + UpdatedPan.X;
    double movedEndY = handEndY + UpdatedPan.Y;

    double radians = Math.Atan2(movedEndY - center.Y, movedEndX - center.X);

    // Convert to degrees
    var angle = radians * (180.0 / Math.PI);
    hand.Rotation = angle;
}
```

Here is an example of how this works.

[image: example]

Comment: is the video how it is actually working, or an example of how you would like it to work?

Comment: I attached a gif of how it works now

Comment: @ivsalti Having a check with this line `var angle = radians * (180.0 / Math.PI);` , `angle` should fit 360 angle direction .